# Custom Link for Homepage adds user ID

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page which I need to associate with custom link. When I add the content of the custom link as visualforce page, on clicking the link it appends user ID to the link due to which the page does not load as it's controller is associated with a custom object and does not identify the user id.

But if I add the custom link content as URL giving a relative path /apex/MyVFPage the redirection works fine.

What is the reason for above behavior ?

EX VF PAGE:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="TestController" showHeader="true">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

EX CONTROLLER:

```
public class TestController{

    public Id testId;
    public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        testId = controller.getId();
    }
}
```

[image: error image]

Comment: can you post your VF page?

Comment: Rao I have added a example VF page and controller to the page and attached a image of error for reference

Comment: to start with your standard controller is account and 005XXXXXXX is a case ID, change ?id="" part to id="001XXXXXXX". What are you trying to do? You have a page but it pretty much does nothing. If you can briefly say what you need, I can take a shot at it.

Comment: well to start with 005XXX is User ID. 500XXXX is a case ID. I am just trying to link the VF page to custom link(Regardless of what the page does). So when I click on custom link it will take me to that page. So when I associate my VF page to custom link by going to   Setup->Customize->Home->Custom Links  and add that custom link to the home page layout, it appends user ID by default.

Comment: my bad on the 005 vs 500 part.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT AN ANSWER, EXTENDED OBSERVATION:**

I do not know why but on the homepage even before you click the link, when you inspect the custom link salesforce appends the ?id=user_id.

You can have a basic vf page with no standard controller/ extension and have a custom VF page link on the homepage and this is the resulting javascript page that opens up.

> javascript:openIntegration%28%27https%3A%2F%2Fpradhap-dev-ed--prao6308.na14.visual.force.com%2Fapex%2Ftestpage%3Fid%3D**005d0000000r6Si**%27%2C%20%27height%3D600%2Clocation%3Dno%2Cresizable%3Dyes%2Ctoolbar%3Dno%2Cstatus%3Dno%2Cmenubar%3Dno%2Cscrollbars%3D1%27%2C%201%29

I created another custom link with execute javascript behavior and the resulting html on the homepage does not have the user_id appended (or) as you pointed create custom link as URL. These options might be workarounds, but honestly no clue on why salesforce might do the append part. Would be interesting to find out by raising a case.

```
<a href="javascript:window.invokeOnClickJS_00bd00000022k88%28this%29">link as js</a>
```

[image]

Comment: @sfdcfox do you have any clue on why the user_id might be appended in the custom link?

Comment: Thanks for checking on this. Good idea to open a case for further explanation on this.